# Push Notification icon is blank in android 13 in unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I don't know why push notification icon is not visible **in android 13** , but working perfectly on other android devices.
Please check out the attached screenshot.

[screenshot of android 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aKTy.jpg)

I just simply integrated firebase push notification and implemented all the code needed in unity, works fine on all android devices when i send a push notification from server but icon is missing in android 13.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: its solved now , please see my comment below